# Moving files between folders

Tags: r, file-io, file-copying

I want to copy/paste a file from one folder to another folder in windows using R, but it's not working.  My code:

```
> file.rename(from="C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/rabata.txt",to="C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/Halwa/BADMASHI/SCOP/rabata.tx")

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Does the BADMASHI/SCOP folder already exist?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax; make sure the source file and dest folder already exist.

Comment: did you try `file.copy` instead of `file.rename`?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, please state the exact error you got.

Comment: What does `file.exists("C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/rabata.txt")` tell you?

Comment: > file.exists("C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/rabata.txt")
[1] TRUE

Comment: `> file.exists("C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/Halwa/BADMASHI/SCOP")
[1] TRUE`  <br/>but > file.exists("C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/Halwa/BADMASHI/SCOP/")
[1] FALSE

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you wanted a `file.rename()`-like function that would also *create* any directories needed to carry out the rename, you could try something like this:

```
my.file.rename <- function(from, to) {
    todir <- dirname(to)
    if (!isTRUE(file.info(todir)$isdir)) dir.create(todir, recursive=TRUE)
    file.rename(from = from,  to = to)
}

my.file.rename(from = "C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/rabata.txt",
               to = "C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/Halwa/BADMASHI/SCOP/rabata.txt")
```

Comment: I am trying to move a file from `/tmp` to `~`, but I am getting a `'Invalid cross-device link'`, how could I solve this?

Comment: `file.rename` cannot move files between different mount points. I guess that in your case /tmp and /home are on separate partitions and mount points.
In such a case you can either do a copy and then remove the old file, or you can use `file_move` from the `fs` package, which seems to be able to move files across mount points.

Answer (score 41):

Please just be aware that `file.rename` will actually delete the file from the "from" folder. If you want to just make a duplicate copy and leave the original in its place, use `file.copy` instead.

Comment: Is file.rename written such that if the process is interrupted, the file won't be lost or corrupted?

Answer (score 17):

Use `file.copy()`   or `fs::file_copy()`

```
file.copy(from = "path_to_original_file",
          to   = "path_to_move_to")
```

Then you can remove the original file with `file.remove()`:

```
file.remove("path_to_original_file")
```

Update 2021-10-08: you can also use `fs::file_copy()`. I like [`{fs}`](https://fs.r-lib.org/index.html) for consistent file and directory management from within R.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the `filesstrings` library. This option will move the file into a directory. Example code:

First, we create a sample directory and file:

```
dir.create("My_directory")
file.create("My_file.txt")
```

Second, we can move `My_file.txt` into the created directory `My_directory`:

```
file.move("My_file.txt", "My_directory")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fs::file_move("oldfile.txt", "some/other/existing/directory/newfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "t" letter in the second extension. Try this:

```
file.rename(from="C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/rabata.txt",to="C:/Users/msc2/Desktop/Halwa/BADMASHI/SCOP/rabata.txt").
```

Additionally, it could be worth it to try the `file.copy()` function. It is specifically designed to copy files instead of renaming.