# R - moving multiple files between folders

Tags: r, relocation

Building on the question that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266963/moving-files-between-folders) about using file.rename in R to move a single file from ond folder to another, is there a way to build a looping function in R that would move all (multiple) files from one folder to another existing folder without having to explicitly name all of the indivdual files?

If possible, I would like to keep the original folder intact so I can start to fill it with fresh files after moving the old ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of questions in that directions; here is one of them [Looping through all files in directory in R, applying multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958516/looping-through-all-files-in-directory-in-r-applying-multiple-commands) but even that one is marked as a duplicate.
The idea is to use list.files - potentially with the "pattern" argument to only grab files of a certain name or type. Yo copy files you could look into file.copy under ?file.copy