# Copying files of specific format from a folder and sub-folders and paste them into a new folder

Tags: r, file, copy, paste

I am trying to copy Java files by listing them from a folder (guava-master) and sub-folders (that is the reason I used the recursive function) using the code below

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/shahr/Documents/master_unzip/guava-master/", pattern="*.java", recursive = TRUE)
```

The above list is fine but then...

I tried to paste them into a new folder using the code below

```
file.copy(filenames, "C:/Users/shahr/Documents/")
```

However, the output I receive is FALSE for all the files and I don't see any files being copied. Am I making any mistake?

many thanks.

Comment: Try adding `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files` so that the directory information is included. Or setting your working directory to `setwd("C:/Users/shahr/Documents/master_unzip/guava-master/")`. Not sure if you need to preserve the subdirectory structure...

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266963/moving-files-between-folders

Comment: @Gregor, Thanks! It worked. :)